# How do I add a custom button with arbitrary function to GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I'd like to know how to add a custom button somewhere in the gimp interface that could do some arbitrary function.  Examples:

- click button and it creates a rectangular selection 10% smaller than current image dimensions
- click button and a horizontal guide is added to image at 20%.

I'm willing to some programming in python or Script-fu.  Is this possible in GIMP? And if so how?

Answer (score 1):

You can write plugins in Python, and add them in arbitrary menus location (in the image windows, or in the right click menu of various lists: Layers, Paths, Brushes...).

These plugins can also have their own windowed interface (PyGtk...).

But what you cannot do is adding buttons in the UI...